# MATLAB - display multiple images with a scrollbar

Tags: matlab

I have a set of 100 images that are saved in a cell array and I want to display them all in one gui window . Of course , if I only use the "subplot" function, they will all be displayed quite tiny.. example:

```
for i=1:100
  subplot(1,100,i);
  imshow(images{i});
end
```

and if i use the axes the window does not fit

is possible to display the images horizontally with a scrollbar ?

like in windows : http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/C7gJkI9.jpg

my gui so far : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vo3T.jpg

Comment: Do you mean having all the images collated horizontally, and displaying only a portion of this long image at a time (controlled by the slider) ?. Or displaying images one by one (the slider used to choose the current image). Are all your images of the same dimension ?

Comment: yes like in windows : http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/C7gJkI9.jpg